# Extract window to another session in tmux

Tags: tmux

I can do it in two commands:

`new-session` - creates new session.

`move-window -t {session-name}:` - moves current window to session 1.

I'd like to bind those to a key, but I haven't found a way to make them work automatically. There's no variable `#{last-created-session}`.

Is there a way to automate this?

Answer (score 2):

Do it with the shell and run-shell, something like:

```
bind m run "S=$(tmux new -dP); tmux movew -t$S"
```